# Delete a cookie if the key start by X in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, unset

I got some cookie start by XYZ and I want to unset them when the user access to a specific route.

So I code :

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
        if (preg_match('/^XYZ/', $key))
            unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
```

But the cookies still there.
I really don't understand because when I do :

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
        if (preg_match('/^XYZ/', $key))
            echo($_COOKIE[$key]);
```

... it works. So I wonder if it is possible to unset cookies like above.

Comment: Why making it complex with `preg_match` if `substr` would work just as well (probably even faster)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reset a cookie like:

```
setcookie($key,"",time()-3600);
```

Comment: So this line of code does not actually unset the cookie, but it resets it to a null value, though we believe it to be unsetting it as it kinda clears the cookie value as well...so by doing that you unset your cookie as you wished to and thats it...done

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'XYZ') === 0) { // check if name starts with 'XYZ'
         setcookie($key, "", (time() - 3600) ); // Set the time which already expired
    }
}
```

With `preg_match` -

```
if (preg_match('/^XYZ/', $key)) {
     setcookie($key, "", (time() - 3600) );
}
```

Comment: Question is for removing cookie, you are unsetting some array element from array $_COOKIE

Comment: I first code your code but I prefer the semantic of a code using preg_match. Both doesn't work by the way for unset the cookie, but works for echo the value.

Comment: Thanks, but William puts the solution first. He got the vote. Thanks for the explanation tho.