# How to completely delete $_COOKIEs in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following PHP script:

```
foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {
  if( strpos( $key, 'ticketRecon_ID-' ) === false ) continue;
  else {
    setcookie( $key, '', time() - 1 );
    unset( $_COOKIE[$key] );
  }
}
```

When I run the script, `print_r($_COOKIE)` shows me the targeted cookies have been deleted and do not exist. Yet the Chrome dev tool inspector shows the cookies are still present (see screen shot below) And when I return to the page where the cookies where created they are still present.

**How do you completely delete/erase/destroy a `_COOKIE` in PHP? Might this have any bearing or relation to the site pages using the SSL protocol?**

[image]

**AMENDED:**

Here is how I initially set the cookie:

`setcookie( 'ticketRecon_ID-' . $row['reservationID'], 'N', null, '/' );`

Comment: Hope this will help you, But i know you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018480/delete-a-cookie-if-the-key-start-by-x-in-php/34018554#34018554)

Comment: Thanks @WilliamMadede...so your answer `setcookie($key,"",time()-3600);` works where my `setcookie( $key, '', time() - 1 );` does not? What's the difference?

Comment: So how do you set the cookie first..?done

Comment: Good question @WilliamMadede ... see my amended OQ

Comment: I copied and pasted your solution verbatim @WilliamMadede `setcookie($key,"",time()-3600);` and it did not work for me.

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that the site pages are under the `https://` protocol.

Comment: solved it ! I need to delete them EXACTLY the same way I created them. IN other words, I was missing the _path_ `, '/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

It seems you must delete a `_COOKIE` the same exact and identical way you create them. So I was missing the path attribute on my delete `setcookie()`.

Created like this `setcookie( 'ticketRecon_ID-' . $row['reservationID'], 'N', null, '/' );`

So delete must be like this `setcookie( $key, '', time() - 1, '/' );`

Hope this post helps someone someday.

Answer (score -2):

Assign it an empty array

```
$_COOKIE = array();
```

Comment: That doesn't delete cookies, it just clears the superglobal

Comment: Thank you @Machavity I got it now.